Can an Android AppWidget's initialLayout be modified before onUpdate?
Modifying an AppWidget's views is relatively trivial, but the recommended mechanism used to do so is the onUpdate method of the AppWidgetProvider-extended class. The problem I am having is that, in my specific case, there is a long delay between when the initialLayout shows up and when the onUpdate method is finally triggered. So is there some other way to do this?
Some specifics: My organization uses a bunch of rooted, generic Android tablets that load a hodgepodge of kludgy crap at startup. This means that when users first power on their tablets, it sometimes takes upward of a minute and a half before the onUpdate method runs, and during that time, the widget is on-screen in its initialLayout state -- no user customization. This means that users think that something has gone wrong with their widget settings.
The ideal solution, of course, is for IT to clean up their startup mess, but that is not a politically viable option for me.
It doesn't matter whether I save the widget customizations to SharedPreferences or an external file -- the problem is that until onUpdate triggers, it seems like the only resources available seem to be those hardcoded into R., like drawables and strings. Is there maybe a way to change @string values programmatically? Any advice on this issue would be much appreciated.

"it sometimes takes upward of a minute and a half before the onUpdate method runs, and during that time, the widget is on-screen in its initialLayout state" -- have you experimented with other launchers, to see if you can find one that maybe isn't as sluggish about requesting the first updates? Have you tried identifying some other trigger that you can use to push changes over yourself? "Is there maybe a way to change @string values programmatically?" -- not in the way that you are suggesting.

@CommonsWare: I have not been able to try other launchers -- that's because changing the launcher and the crap that runs on boot are, as mentioned above, not politically viable -- but I have tried different triggers. For instance, I've tried onReceive as a trigger, but no luck there, either. I've also tried wrapping the entire application in an activity using <application android:name="WrapperActivity"> in AndroidManifest.xml and using the onCreate method there, but that hasn't worked for me either. There is still that ~80 second delay on boot.

"not politically viable" -- one would hope that it would be "politically viable" to run an experiment. "For instance, I've tried onReceive as a trigger, but no luck there, either" -- onReceive() of what broadcast? ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED? If that gets to you, maybe you push app widget information through AppWidgetManager every few seconds from then until you get onUpdate() and know that the launcher is going to start requesting updates. That might not help, but if the launcher ignores live app widget content, there isn't much you can do about that.

@CommonsWare: You have inspired me to experiment even further with which broadcasts I can pick up in onReceive(), and after a bit of testing, I've confirmed that the problem is that the BroadcastReceiver isn't loading for those first ~80 seconds after boot. This effectively kills the idea of finding some other trigger (such as ACTION_BOOT_COMPLETED) and keying off of that ... which will give me more ammunition for my political battle with the group that handles the initial setup of these tablets. Wish me luck.
